# Change Request in ActionFilter By Property attributes

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, attributes, action-filter

I am coding a `.Net core` API that serves `administrators` and `employees`. These people see the same interface.

The only difference is that the `manager` can view the `profile` of other employees. The employee can only view his own profile. I am using `JWT`. I have completed the development for the administrator section.

I want to use the same APIs in the employee section as well. But in this section, I need to get `employeeId` from `JWT`, not from the request.

I created an attribute for the fields representing the employeeId. Example:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<AddressDto>> Get(long deciderType, [EmployeeId] long deciderId)
```

I want to have an action filter, in that `action filter` if it has the desired role, I want to give the `employeeId` in `JWT` to the request variable that has this attribute. In this case to deciderId. Is this possible? I could not find a way to filter the request parameters by attribute.

Or is there a better way to do this? I can do these operations in different APIs with the same business but I am not sure if this is the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to separate your Get APIs and set **Authrozie** Attribute with **Role Admin** for your administrator, and also one another Get for **employees**.

If you have created your **JWT** like this

```
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
  Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString())
            }),
  Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
  SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), 
  SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
};
```

Now in your Get method which belongs to the employee, you do not need to send EmployeeId and you can get it from the JWT token

```
var claimsIdentity = this.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
var userId = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
```

In conclusion, you would have two Get endpoints.

For **Administrator**

```
 [Authorize(Role=RolesEnumeration.Admin)]
 public async Task<IActionResult<AddressDto>> Get()
 {
       //get all addresses from the DB by pagination
 }
```

And for **employees**

```
public async Task<IActionResult<AddressDto>> Get()
 {
     var claimsIdentity = this.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
     var userId = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;

     //get employee address from the DB by userId
 }
```